# BAPI to get customer company?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi, function-module

Customer company is stored in KNB1 table.

I tried with BAPI_CUSTOMER_GETDETAIL2, seems it does not expose company code. Instead of it, company code is the bapi input.

I am looking for a BAPI that can give company code from given customer number. Is there any bapi existed?

Comment: The problem is that the customer can be created for one ccode, for multiple or for none at all, and thus can be non-existent in KNB1. So far I found no BAPIs for this task, it will be faster to create your own small BAPI than to search forever.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding what a [company code](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6a49d1604ffc4b908f9f78fba3824187/6.17.17/en-US/3a27d153c9684608e10000000a174cb4.html) is actually for? A company code is an organizational unit in your own system. It's not an external company you do business with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no BAPI for that, because what you want to do does not make sense on a conceptual level. A customer does not have a company code. A customer can have company code specific data for any number of company codes. When there is a `n..1` relationship between customers and company codes in your system, then that's something unique to how your organization uses it. On a technical level, the relationship is `n..m`.

But if you want a table of all company codes (BUKRS) which have data for a specific customer (KUNNR), you can do that with a simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT bukrs FROM knb1 INTO TABLE @lt_bukrs WHERE kunnr = @lv_kunnr.
```